# Writing a search method that matches loosely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, railscasts

I have just watched the railscast about a [simple search form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form) and I want to do something like that in my app, but I don't want to find just results that match exactly.

I have a model named `Project` with the following fields:

- `name`,
- `description`,
- `keyword1`, and
- `keyword2`.

Given the code taken from the railscast:

```
models/project.rb

def self.search(search)
    if search
        find( :all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"] )
    else
        find(:all)
    end
end
```

If I want to search for "Pizza", and I would want it to match a project named "Master Pizza Project" with keyword1 => "MasterPizza" and keyword2 => "Pizza", how would I refactor the above code?

Also, is case sensitivity a problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is another railscast where Ryan Bates talks about utilizing Sphinx to make full text search. I would highly recommend such an approach instead of doing things from scratch :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to split the query into atoms, run each atom as a separate query then merge the results from each atom.

At this point things are getting pretty complex, you'd be better off using a search library such as [Acts as Indexed](https://github.com/dougal/acts_as_indexed) which takes care of all this for you.

[Disclosure] I'm the author of Acts as Indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Metasearch](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) and [Metawhere](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) gems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your q but I hope this makes sense:

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
     where('title LIKE ? OR keyword1 LIKE ? OR keyword2 LIKE ?',"%#{search}%", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
    # find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      all
    end
  end
```